# disable `trim_blocks` for `blockinfile` module

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html?highlight=trim_blocks) of Ansible 2.7 allows to disable the [`trim_blocks`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control) setting of jinja2.

What I want is to disable this setting for the [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) module, but don't find any information about it. I even tried to use the template lookup plugin with any look.

Is there a way to disable this in a play for `blockinfile`?

I do need this for additional whitespace control. Consider for example the following (simplified and stripped-down) template for an SSH config file:

```
{%- for host in groups.linux %}
{%- set vars = hostvars[host] %}
Host {{ vars.inventory_hostname_short }}
{#- add the fqdn as alias if present #}
{%- if host != vars.inventory_hostname_short %} {{ host }}{% endif %}
Hostname {{ vars.ansible_ssh_host }}
IdentityFile {{ vars.ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}
{% endfor %}
```

This allows me to control one empty line between entries and to append content (the fqdn in this case) to the previous line. With `trim_blocks` enabled I would need to concat strings in variables, or is there a better way to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure the template

```
> cat my_template.j2
#jinja2: trim_blocks:False
{%- for host in groups.linux %}
(continue)
```

and use it in *blockinfile*

```
- blockinfile:
    block: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_template.j2') }}"
  (continue)
```